# Jquery: Set a timeout of a page for loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, loading

i would like make a script that detect if the page is full loading in 30 or else refresh the page with method (CTRL + F5) of Firefox that clear the cache of that page and refresh..
Is possibile to make?
P.S: If is not possibile to make in Jquery i can use normal javascript.
Thanks in advance.
Kind Regards.
Luca.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### plain JavaScript

```
var loaded = false;
var time = 30000;
window.onload = function() {
     loaded = true;
 };
setTimeout(function() {
     if(!loaded) {
         window.location.reload();
     }

},time);
```

### jQuery

```
var loaded = false;
var time = 30000;
$(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {
       loaded = true;
    });
    setTimeout(function() { 
        if(!loaded) {
            window.location.reload();
        }  
    },time);
});
```

Comment: You can also use `window.location.reload()`.

Answer (score 5):

You can write this in your html head:

```
<meta id="meta-refresh" http-equiv="refresh" content="30; URL=(your url)">
```

It refreshes the page after 30 seconds.
In your jQuery part there could be something like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#meta-refresh").remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks you too,but i was need a function to add in a external script and in a page :-(   Thanks you anyway ;-)